# Two languages on site asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I study a lesson which describes how to create a site with two or more languages,
and the first step in the lesson - I need to add the following code in my project

```
  context.MapRoute(
            name: "lang",
            url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints : new { lang = @"ru|en" },
            namespaces: new[] { "LessonProject.Areas.Default.Controllers" }
        );

        context.MapRoute(
            name : "default",
            url : "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults : new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, lang = "ru" },
            namespaces : new [] { "LessonProject.Areas.Default.Controllers" }
        );
```

in file `DefaultAreaRegistration (/Areas/Default/DefaultAreaRegistration.cs)`
but I dont have this file in my project.
I dont understand I need to create a new folder Areas and a new file DefaultAreaRegistration.cs or I need to change RouteConfig.cs file which contains

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

?
And in **Global.asax** there is the following code
 `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();`

What's part I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this code to DefaultAreaRegistration.cs if this area was created before.
It means that the multiculture route cannot be created automatically when area creating. So if you dont have any Areas in your solution you just need the register route in RouteConfig.cs. its alredy done.
And u dont need any Areas for multyculture functionality.